# Unable to install Subversive Plug-In on Eclipse Mars (4.5.2 )

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

### Unable to install  Subversive Plug-In on Eclipse Mars (4.5.2 )

- Plataform: Windows 7 64 bits.
- Eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
- Direct Connection to Internet (Checked)
- BundlePools[Oomph],deleted temp files at user home
  [.eclipse\org.eclipse.oomph.p2\cache]

Tried many install options:

- [Install New Software ] Collaboration  from [ Mars -
  http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars]
- [Install New Software ]Adding uri of lateste  http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/3.0/update-site/
- MartketPlace
- Downloading Subversive-3.0.4.I20160131-1700.zip to install from Local Archive.

Error:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).

**Access denied**

**Unable to read repository at** ..... [ *in this case is reading from the local ;
example
Unable to read repository at jar:file:/D:/example/Subversive-3.0.4.I20160131-1700.zip!/plugins/org.eclipse.team.svn.ui_3.0.4.I20160131-1700.jar.*

**Access denied**
**Unable to write to repository:** ....

Unable to write to repository: file:/D:/eclipse/.

It has  permissions, but i don't know why throws thas exception with "Access Denied", even creates the directory : "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine".

Also probed : put -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true in Eclipse.ini,  Disable Windows Firewall ...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

I answer myself. It is an issue with  the antivirus. Somehow the antivirus not allow decompress and read the downloaded jar, required for installation of pluggin. It occurs most pluggins an versions of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have encountered the same problem. And it seems that the installation works fine if i disable my antivirus.